# Texture UVUnwrap Follow Up-- What did I do wrong?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

Previously I asked a question about [textures not appearing correctly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123084/texturing-not-displaying-fully-on-face). I tried unwrapping it manually and it really hasn't helped very much, as you can see:

[image]

I'm starting to wonder if the texture itself is just too small an image or something, or too large?

Comment: Looks like you need to watch [some beginner tutorials about unwrapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23173/how-do-texture-coordinates-work) and texturing to get the basics first

Comment: open the texture in the UV/image editor so you can see where the texture is in relation to the UV map

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks but I already understood and know about the information in that thread, I should have mentioned I've watched a tutorial already.

Comment: @DiogoValadares How do I open the texture in the UV editor?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what I was doing wrong. I deleted my file, and started from scratch. I realized that like what @DiogoValadares said, I have to actually put the "maps" / islands on the texture while in the UV texture editor. Unwrapping it cleanly isn't enough. To do this, go to your UV editor, then in the bottom left to the right of "UVs" tab, press the little image icon and select the texture you want.